# Sharepoint development in what language?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint

I know this might sound a little silly. but I'm confused as to what language does sharepoint code behind uses? do they use vb or c#? or is it possible to use either? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

C#.

You CAN use any .net language that you want of course, but the vast vast majority of SharePoint books, documentation and Code Samples are in C#. The official Microsoft SharePoint SDK Samples is only in C#.

You really want to use C# if you have to develop for SharePoint, especially if you're just starting.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [any language supported by the .NET Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint#Customization), Visual Basic and C# included.

Answer (score 2):

You'll never know for sure.  It could be any language that can compile into a .Net assembly.  I think the advice here is that it is most likely C# but it would be hard for someone to say definitely that every code behind in the product was written with C#.

In short, write with what you know and like.  If you are just learning and don't have a preference, stick with C#.

Answer (score 0):

Lets just say 9 out of 10 uses C# as the code behind although this is not proven. But that's the way how I rate it in terms of community, samples and all the persons I know. Haven't seen somebody to use VB as codebehind yet but I'm sure there is. It would actually depend on what language you are comfortable it has no actual requirments for the code behind for as long as it is in .Net :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some vb.net codebehind, but honestly that was more to show that they could also write it in vb.net than out of a preference. I started in vb.net when .net just surfaced and I must admit that I changed to c# after 3 months and I never regretted that afterwards :)